# magento - including php file in the root folder

Tags: php, magento, session

I have a product page in magento where I have a drop down menu and a submit button.
When I choose a value from the drop down menu and click submit, I send the request to a file called other.php in the root of the magento installation.

This is all fine.

On this page I set a session variable $_SESSION['myGroupID'] and I have successfully echoed this out so I know that's ok.

When I go to redirect back to the referring page, the `$_SESSION['myGroupID']` is not persisting. I have included `session_start();` on all required pages.

I suspect it's because I'm breaking out of magento's world here, off to a php file that I created in the root and back again to a page in magento's world.

Can someone tell me what I need to do in order to "teach" magento that this other.php file is part of the overall set up, and what I would need to include to allow the session variable to persist across my pages?

I saw this link which looks to be a similar problem, but I'm new to Magento and don't quite understand the information in it.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/adding-magentos-required-structure-to-a-php-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the below code at the top of your external file.

```
<?php
 require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
 umask(0);
 Mage::app('default');
 //Get the session object
 $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
 $groupid = $session->getMyGroupId();
```

You need to define your session in another page like

```
$data = 'GroupId';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyGroupId($data);
```

Let me know if you are having any issues.

Comment: great - i'll give this a try tonight. i appreciate the response - thanks!

Comment: this seems to have worked but i've run into another problem around retaining the session value using magento methods. i have created a new question - thanks for helping with this one.

Comment: new question here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955725/session-wont-persist-on-reload-in-magento